# React Native project, sometimes getting 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001' using expo start

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using `expo-cli` 2.6.14, `react-native` 0.57.1, Expo SDK 31.0.0. In order to start the project to run on the Expo app, I use `expo start`. Sometimes it works, sometimes I get an error and I have no idea why. If I just keep running `expo start` over and over again, eventually it will work, but that's a lot of wasted time.

This is the error that I get:

```
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I'm not sure why this happens. I've been ignoring it since it doesn't happen consistently, but it's become a nuisance. Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Edit: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/52) that still has not been fixed.

Edit 2: Still occurring with `expo-cli` 2.12.2, and Expo SDK 33.0.0

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I faced this issue too, here is what I did finally:

First try to use "expo start -c" to clear the cache when launching, this is the option that works every time.

Try to delete your .expo folder if it doesn't work and retry.

Comment: In case this solution does not work, I have posted an alternative solution.

Answer (score 7):

For whatever reason, this is the solution that works almost 100% of the times for me.

- `expo start`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- `expo start`

Answer (score 7):

I followed below steps:

1. Run `expo start`
2. Ctrl + c
3. Delete .expo folder in your project directory
4. Run `expo build:android -c`

⚠️**expo build:android will be discontinued on January 4, 2023**⚠️

Answer (score 6):

Try removing the `.expo` directory from the project root.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. I resolved it by deleting the `.expo` folder in the root of my project

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to  start expo

expo start
 and after build your project

expo publish

use this two command it is worked for me.

Comment: thanks Dynamic Methods. my problem is solved by using this

Comment: Thanks For your valuable Feedback.

Comment: The issue was that `expo start` itself wasn't working

Comment: @zaytrix Your Project is expo detached Project??  if not then use exp start otherwise you can use this two command.

Comment: I have to face this problem when I was building my project in iOS that time I got this error and I have used these two command and it is working for me

Answer (score 1):

I have recently created an app in react-native and I used command "expo build-android" for creating the Android APK.It even worked for me most of the times but not always, so the solution I used is (might be helpful to someone else) -

1. Run command "npm install -g expo-cli" and this throws an error - "expo is unrecognised as internal and external commands"
2. Search for "environment variables”(Press windows key to search on Windows OS) and add a new path to system variables "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm" you might have different folder at the place of "test", use that here.
3. Run "npm install -g expo-cli" and it should work fine.
4. Run "expo build:android" if it still gives the same error then run 3 commands in command prompt (now go to the project path then run these 3 commands one after another) step-1: expo start step-2: ctrl+c (to stop it) step-3: expo build:android
   It’s not clear to me as to why this works and how I came to this solution but its working.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check what 19xxx ports are being used by what applications. You can do so by running 'expo start -c' from one terminal and run 'netstat' and 'lsof' commands from another terminal. You can kill other processes if they're using any of 19xxx ports.

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Specific situation but I found out that [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/valet) running in the background was causing me to consistently get the `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001` error.

Running `valet stop` before `expo start` seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal.
Write `ipconfig`, you'll get IP4 address like: 192.168.........
Copy this address and run this:
`set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=(paste you ip4 address here)`
Now run: `expo start`
Open split terminal and run: `expo build:android`

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your .expo folder as it is recommended in the [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/common-development-errors/#metro-bundler-econnrefused-12700119001)

Worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

run #rm -rf .expo in your project folder

Answer (score 0):

Adding some additional info...

Like others stated, I tried doing the `expo start` then ctrl+c.  It seemed to work at first, but then my build failed with

`EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'mypath\.expo\packager-info.json.1807243929' -> 'mypath\.expo\packager-info.json'`

So then I removed .expo like the others and then my build worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just **delete the .expo file from your root director**y of the project and run the command
**Don't Touch The .expo-shared file**

```
expo android:build
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked when I closed another process.

make sure you don't have antoher process running in the same port, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to solving problems like this is to find out what is using the port in question.

Try on Windows

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 127.0.0.1:19001
```

In the last column it will show a PID code, write it down.

Press Windows + R and type

```
taskmgr
```

The task manager will open, go to the service area and look for the PID you wrote down earlier and when you find it, end the process.

After that try to run a build.