# Expo project error Could not connect to development server after updating expo SDK

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a project a while back and tried running it recently and got an error from expo saying that my SDK version is not up to date. So I followed this answer ([The experience you requested uses Expo SDK v(null), but this copy of Expo Client requires at least v23.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287710/the-experience-you-requested-uses-expo-sdk-vnull-but-this-copy-of-expo-client)) to fix it. However now I'm running into a new error where my project cannot run and I get this error:

> Could no connect to development server

What can I do to fix this? I don't want to try a hundred different solutions and accidentally lose my project forever and have to start over, so I figured I'd ask on here.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "firebase": "^6.5.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.18.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-smart-carousel": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "truffle": "^5.0.34",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "web3": "0.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I ran `expo-cli --version` in my terminal and this is what I received:

```sh
3.0.4
```

Thank you

Comment: can you please post your `package.json` file also can you run on your terminal `expo-cli --version` what is the output?

Comment: @AbdeenM. I just edited my post, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Run `npm install -g expo-cli` to install the latest Expo CLI globally.
2. Close your Expo CLI server if you are using it.
3. Make sure in `app.json` the `sdkVersion` is `33.0.0`
4. Change the `react` dependency in your `package.json` from `16.5.0` to `16.8.3`
5. Delete your project `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file
6. Run `npm install` or `yarn install` depending on your package manager.
7. Run `expo start -c` to clear your cache and start your application.

---

### Bonus

Now for any Expo based API or dependency you can install it by using `expo install` instead of `npm install` i.e. `expo install @expo/vector-icons`.
This is better than using the traditional `npm install` or `yarn install` as it will install the version of the dependency that's compatible with your current Expo SDK.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I am receiving this error now `ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/me/Folder/MyProject/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts'`

Comment: Run this on your project directory `expo install @expo/vector-icons` that should do it :)

Comment: I am sorry, but now I am getting this error: `spawn yarnpkg ENOENT
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.`

Comment: what is your OS? do you use npm or yarn?

Comment: my OS is 10.14.5 and I use npm

Comment: how are you running your project? using `exp start` or `expo start`?

Comment: I use expo start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201123/discussion-between-abdeen-m-and-frank-gully).

Comment: In addition to @Abdeen answer, you should try deleting .expo, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119066/11127383

Answer (score 3):

The issue has to do with watchman & brew.

Follow these steps, by running:

1. `npm r -g watchman`
2. `brew update && brew upgrade`
3. `brew install --build-from-source python@3.10` (Optional)
4. `brew install watchman`

Make sure to run sudo if you are having permission issues.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me (and others) is to remove watchman (on Mac):

`brew uninstall watchman`

See also https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29587#issuecomment-886284902